# border causes div to overlap past 100% by 1 or 2px

Tags: css

I have our navigation bar set to 100%.  The bar also has a 1px border on it.  For some reason, the border causes the nav bar to stick out to the right by 1 or 2 pixels.  I tried setting the border to 0 in Firebug and sure enough, it lined up correctly.  Our site is here: http://clubschoicefundraising.com/

As you can see, the blue nav bar at the top stick out to the left side.  I can remove the "right: 0" and then it sticks out to the right side.  How do I prevent the border from causing the nav bar to stick out?

Update: As requested, here is my CSS for the nav:

```
nav 
{
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 70px;
margin-top: 5px;
font-size: 1.3em;
font-weight: 600;
list-style: none;
width: 100%;
margin: 5px auto;
height: 43px;
padding: 0;
z-index: 10;

/* Background color and gradients */
background: #014464;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);    
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0272a7), to(#013953));
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3C78B9, #28507B);    
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#3C78B9), to(#28507B));
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3C78B9, #28507B);  

/* Borders */
border: 1px solid #002232;

box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
}
```

Comment: Can someone clue me in to the negative votes and votes to close the question?

Comment: the problem is that even if you link to your website, you need to reproduce your issue with minimum code and post the code here mainly for 2 reasons : 1) it is much easier to answer question with short code 2) what happens when your site goes offline... this question won't be of any use for further users.

Comment: see here for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation :**

By default, borders are calculated outside a specified with on an element,that is why it overflows when you give your element a border.

**Solution :**

Use `box-sizing:border-box;` so that the border width is calculated inside the 100% and it won't overflow. ([more info on box sizing on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing))

`box-sizing:border-box;` is supported by IE8+ ([see canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing))

Answer (score 1):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to your `nav`

```
nav {
box-sizing: border-box;--> ADDED
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 70px;
margin-top: 5px;
font-size: 1.3em;
font-weight: 600;
list-style: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100%;
margin: 5px auto;
height: 43px;
padding: 0;
z-index: 10;
background: #014464;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0272a7), to(#013953));
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3C78B9, #28507B);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#3C78B9), to(#28507B));
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3C78B9, #28507B);
border: 1px solid #002232;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
}
```

For more info about `box-sizing` you can refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the computed `width` of the element exceeds the available space inside its parent.

`<div>` elements - other than absolutely positioned ones - will take up the available width of their parent.

However in this particular instance that you have removed the element from normal flow by using `absolute` positioning, you could specify the width  of the element - stretch the element - by `left: 0; right: 0;` declarations which is supposed to work on a large scale of web browsers.

Alternatively, you could use [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) declaration to make the UAs calculate the `width`/`height` of the box including the borders and padding.

It's worth noting that the second approach is supported in IE 8 and above.

Comment: Just note that by using `left: 0; right: 0;` you should **NOT** add `width: 100%` anymore.